# Modifying zsh globbing patterns to use with cp

Tags: shell-script, zsh, file-copy, patterns, glob

I'm trying to write a script to copy files recursively from a particular folder except files `A.extn`, `B/*.extn` and `C/*` where `B` and `C` are directories and `extn` is just some generic extension. This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
TMPDIR=/tmp/test

cp -pR $(dirname $0)/**~(*.foo/*|*/bar.txt|*.abc|qux.txt) $TMPDIR
```

However this doesn't do the negation of the pattern as expected. I think I do know why — although the pattern is correct (as seen with `echo`), `cp -R` is not aware of the pattern, and enters a directory that it is "not supposed to", and once in there, the pattern is no longer valid.

How do I modify the above to do what I want? I guess it is possible with `find` and `xargs`, but I'm drawn towards the clarity of the above and would prefer something similar (but if it's the wrong way to do it, I'd be perfectly happy with a different solution).

Comment: Globbing isn't command-specific, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the pattern is expanded before `cp` is run, so is unknown to that command.

You may be able to accomplish what you want by using the `--parents` option to `cp` rather than `-R`.  That will only copy the files which match your pattern, but will use the full path name as supplied rather than only the trailing file name.

But, this option isn't portable.  AFAIK, it's only supported by the GNU version of cp.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I don't care for portability, as this is for use on this particular machine which has GNU cp.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern may exclude the files you don't want to copy, but it doesn't exclude the directories containing them, and you told `cp` to copy recursively. So the files are copied anyway. Worse than that, if you have a source tree like

```
foo
foo/bar.txt
hello
hello/world
hello/world/wibble.txt
```

then the pattern expands to `foo hello hello/world hello/world/wibble.txt` so you end up with these files in `$TMPDIR`:

```
foo
foo/bar.txt
hello
hello/world
hello/world/wibble.txt
wibble.txt
world
world/wibble.txt
```

This has nothing to do with the pattern being “no longer valid”. The pattern is expanded by the shell, `cp` only sees the list of files.

You need to use a copying tool that can exclude files as it's doing the recursive traversal.

You can use zcp for that, but it won't copy the directories, and it won't create target directories automatically. The easiest tool for this job is rsync. Pax is another option.

```
rsync -a --exclude='*.foo/*' --exclude='bar.txt' --exclude='*.abc' --exclude='/qux.txt' $(dirname $0) $TMPDIR
```